# (float) и xml в PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
$result = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><digiseller.response><retval>0</retval><amount>0,1</amount></digiseller.response>';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);

$amount = (float) $xml->amount;
```

Почему `$amount = 0`? Должен 0.1 быть же. С `floatval` тоже самое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разделителем между целой и дробной частью должна быть точка, а не запятая.

Comment: вот так вот сайт отдаёт инфорацию. Позор мне, что не догадался. Спасибо :/